# an illegal memory access was encountered using PyCUDA and TensorRT

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycuda, tensorrt

I used TensorRT in python code. So I use PyCUDA.
In the following inference code, there is `an illegal memory access was encountered` happened at `stream.synchronize()`.

```
def infer(engine, x, batch_size, context):  
    inputs = []
    outputs = []
    bindings = []
    stream = cuda.Stream()
    for binding in engine:
        size = trt.volume(engine.get_binding_shape(binding)) * batch_size
        dtype = trt.nptype(engine.get_binding_dtype(binding))
        # Allocate host and device buffers
        host_mem = cuda.pagelocked_empty(size, dtype)
        device_mem = cuda.mem_alloc(host_mem.nbytes)
        # Append the device buffer to device bindings.
        bindings.append(int(device_mem))
        # Append to the appropriate list.
        if engine.binding_is_input(binding):
            inputs.append(HostDeviceMem(host_mem, device_mem))
        else:
            outputs.append(HostDeviceMem(host_mem, device_mem))
    img = np.array(x).ravel()
    np.copyto(inputs[0].host, 1.0 - img / 255.0)  
    [cuda.memcpy_htod_async(inp.device, inp.host, stream) for inp in inputs]
    context.execute_async(batch_size=batch_size, bindings=bindings, stream_handle=stream.handle)    
    # Transfer predictions back from the GPU.
    [cuda.memcpy_dtoh_async(out.host, out.device, stream) for out in outputs]
    # Synchronize the stream
    stream.synchronize()
    # Return only the host outputs.

    return [out.host for out in outputs]
```

What could be wrong?

EDIT:
My program is combination of Tensorflow and TensorRT codes.
The error happened only when I run

```
self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
self.persistent_sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph, config=tf_config)
```

before running infer(). If I don't run the above two lines, I have no issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is I have two python codes.
Say tensorrtcode.py and tensorflowcode.py.

**`tensorrtcode.py has`** only tensorrt codes.

```
def infer(engine, x, batch_size, context):  
    inputs = []
    outputs = []
    bindings = []
    stream = cuda.Stream()
    for binding in engine:
        size = trt.volume(engine.get_binding_shape(binding)) * batch_size
        dtype = trt.nptype(engine.get_binding_dtype(binding))
        # Allocate host and device buffers
        host_mem = cuda.pagelocked_empty(size, dtype)
        device_mem = cuda.mem_alloc(host_mem.nbytes)
        # Append the device buffer to device bindings.
        bindings.append(int(device_mem))
        # Append to the appropriate list.
        if engine.binding_is_input(binding):
            inputs.append(HostDeviceMem(host_mem, device_mem))
        else:
            outputs.append(HostDeviceMem(host_mem, device_mem))
    img = np.array(x).ravel()
    np.copyto(inputs[0].host, 1.0 - img / 255.0)  
    [cuda.memcpy_htod_async(inp.device, inp.host, stream) for inp in inputs]
    context.execute_async(batch_size=batch_size, bindings=bindings, stream_handle=stream.handle)    
    # Transfer predictions back from the GPU.
    [cuda.memcpy_dtoh_async(out.host, out.device, stream) for out in outputs]
    # Synchronize the stream
    stream.synchronize()
    # Return only the host outputs.

    return [out.host for out in outputs]

def main():
    .....
    infer(......)
    .....
```

Then **`tensorflowcode.py has`** only tensorflow apis and execute with `session`.

```
self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
self.persistent_sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph, config=tf_config)
```

Problem is when I need to interface  class from tensorflow to tensorrt class, 
declare the tensorflow code's class instance inside tensorrt's main as

def main():
   .....
   t_flow_code=tensorflowclass()
   infer(......)
   .....

then I have error as `illegal memory access was encountered happened at stream.synchronize()`

The problem is solved by adding `another session at tensorrt just before t_flow_code=tensorflowclass().`

I don't understand why I need as I have it own session for execution at tensorflow class. Why I need another session before class interface in tensorrt code.